# How to call variables out function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I created this code in javascript, this code work fine, the code use drop-down to select item.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
</head>
<body><br><div id="id6"></div>
    Select an item from the following list:<br />
  <select id="select" onchange="myFuntam()">
   <option value="">choose
  <option value="var_1">car1
  <option value="var_2">car2
  <option value="var_3">car3
  <option value="var_4">car4
</select>
        <script>
   function myFuntam() {
    var x = document.getElementById("select").value;
        url="http//domain1.com";
        ur2="http//domain2.com";
        ur3="http//domain3.com";
        ur4="http//domain4.com";
    var    link_1;
      if (x == "var_1") {
        link_1=url;

   }
       if (x == "var_2") {
        link_1=ur2;

   }
   if (x == "var_3") {
        link_1=ur3;

   }
   if (x == "var_4") {
        link_1=ur4;

   }
    document.getElementById("id6").innerHTML = "You selected: " + link_1;
}




    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now i need to call variable link_1 out of function, allow me to use this variable with another function or any where out the function.
i try to use this code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
</head>
<body><br><div id="id6"></div>
    Select an item from the following list:<br />
  <select id="select" onchange="myFuntam()">
   <option value="">choose
  <option value="var_1">car1
  <option value="var_2">car2
  <option value="var_3">car3
  <option value="var_4">car4
</select>
        <script>
   function myFuntam() {
    var x = document.getElementById("select").value;
        url="http//domain1.com";
        ur2="http//domain2.com";
        ur3="http//domain3.com";
        ur4="http//domain4.com";
    var    link_1;
      if (x == "var_1") {
        link_1=url;

   }
       if (x == "var_2") {
        link_1=ur2;

   }
   if (x == "var_3") {
        link_1=ur3;

   }
   if (x == "var_4") {
        link_1=ur4;

   }
    return link_1;
}
     document.getElementById("id6").innerHTML = "You selected: " + link_1;   



    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

but this code not correct, link_1 is undefined, so how i use link_1 out of function.

Comment: declare link_1 outside your function. Make it global.

Comment: Make link_1 global still undefined

Comment: It will be undefined since you did not yet select something, @D.TAM. You cannot assign something to a variable that will be selected in the *future*. That would be creepy.

Comment: You'll have to explain what your purpose is. What do you need that variable for? What do you expect to happen with it when nothing is selected yet?

Comment: i need only execute this (document.getElementById("id6").innerHTML = "You selected: " + link_1; ) out the function, i submit my full code

Answer (score 0):

The basics to get it done :

```
var link_1 = 'foobar';
function ....() { something with link_1; }
console.log(link_1);
```

Comment: your code is not clear for me, it is better if you add more explain.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the var outside the function so the function changes its declared value and you can keep using it the way you wanted after your function is done.

```js
var link_1;

function myFunction() {
  link_1 = 'www.anysite.com';
}

myFunction();
//now the var can be used outside
console.log(link_1);

//Anothe option could be

var link;

function myFunction2() {
  link = 'www.otherwebsite.com';
  return link;
}

link_2 = myFunction2();
console.log(link_2);
```

The third option could be using localStorage if the other ones did not work.
localStorage.setItem('link_1', link_1_value);
var aLink = localStorage.getItem('link_1');

Choose the one that suits your needs.

Comment: i use global variable( var link_1;)  but still receive undefined, even i did try this before submit my question

Comment: @D.TAM , Have you tried the second option? The first option is one that I use in a project I´m working with nodejs.

Comment: yes, your 2nd option same as my 2nd code i submitted (i added var link_1 ;) and received undefined

Comment: @D.TAM I just put a third option if you want to take a look

Comment: your code is correct, however it is look like did not work with drop-down menu as in my code , i need code can work with drop-down

Comment: @D.TAM That's actually kinda weird. I've been using those three methods with select tags without any Issue. Have you use localStorage?

Comment: This three method work fine in case of no drop_down menu, i tested it without drop_down it is ok, but when i added drop_down it did not work. I try try both local storage and live with the domain.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using a variable, is to store the information in the DOM. You will save some code logic by storing those URL strings in each of the `option` nodes, as HTML5 data attributes.

The selected URL is then quite easily available.

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('select');

function myFuntam() {
    console.log(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].dataset.url);
    return sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].dataset.url;
}
```

```html
Select an item from the following list:<br>
<select id="select" onchange="myFuntam()">
    <option value="">choose
    <option value="var_1" data-url="http//domain1.com">car1</option>
    <option value="var_2" data-url="http//domain2.com">car2</option>
    <option value="var_3" data-url="http//domain3.com">car3</option>
    <option value="var_4" data-url="http//domain4.com">car4</option>
</select>
```

You can of course still decide to store that URL in a global variable, but as you can see, you don't need a lot of logic any more to retrieve it dynamically. Calling the function will just give you the URL you need without much hassle.

Comment: my 1st code work fine like your code, i still need to call link_1 out it's  function

Comment: Sure your code works fine, I am just showing a shorter method, so that you actually can just write `sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].dataset.url`: that *is* your variable. Of course, that will not be accessible unless something is selected.

Comment: your code is correct, however it is look like did not work with drop-down menu as in my code , i need code can work with drop-down

Comment: Huh? The snippet I provided has a drop-down, which I copied from your question. If that is not as in the code you actually have, then why did you not provide *that* in your question? We cannot guess what your actual code looks like.

Comment: I provided full code, your code work very good, however i need to take variable out function, i need to use this (document.getElementById("id6").innerHTML = "You selected: " + link_1; ) out the function

Comment: My point is that you *have* a variable, it just may not look like you expect: `document.getElementById("id6").textContent = "You selected: " + sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].dataset.url;` or `document.getElementById("id6").textContent = "You selected: " + myFuntam();`.

Comment: i understand your code, your code work only when (document.getElementById("id6").textContent = "You selected: " + sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].dataset.url; or document.getElementById("id6").textContent = "You selected: " + myFuntam();) inside myFuntam(){ code work only}, when i replace it out { }of function it did not work, even i use return(it must be work but it did not), (that is my problem i received undefined??

Comment: Please provide a fiddle that demonstrates that produces `undefined` so I am able to tell you why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="id6"></div>
Select an item from the following list:<br />
<select id="select" onchange="myFuntam()">
<option value="">choose
<option value="var_1">car1
<option value="var_2">car2
<option value="var_3">car3
<option value="var_4">car4
</select>
<script>
function myFuntam() {
var x = document.getElementById("select").value;
    url="http//domain1.com";
    ur2="http//domain2.com";
    ur3="http//domain3.com";
    ur4="http//domain4.com";
   var    link_1;
  if (x == "var_1") {
    link_1=url;
}
   if (x == "var_2") {
    link_1=ur2;
 }
 if (x == "var_3") {
    link_1=ur3;
 }
if (x == "var_4") {
    link_1=ur4;
 }
 return link_1;
}
function secondfunction(){
  var linkvalue=myFuntam();
  alert(linkvalue);
}
 document.getElementById("id6").innerHTML = "You selected: " + myFuntam();   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It  is look like this code did not work with drop-down menu as in my code , i need code can work with drop-down